# Question about the relationship between matter and value

Tags: values

Seems most or all of our expressions of material things are stated in various values--36' long, 120 volts, .192mm diameter, etc.  Does this suggest the possibility that matter is just value, i.e., that all expressions of the material realm definitions of various value states?